# Adding text to a static Area of the page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a text area which is having multiple lines.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test1" /> Test1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="test2" /> Test2 <br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="test3" /> Test3 <br /> 


<input type="text" name="testxtoadd" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I want to keep in the text box, 
example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test4" /> Test4 <br />
```

and check submit and the text should be added on the Top after text3.

How to achieve this. I'm not sure how to proceed? Am I missing something on how to dynamically update a panel/area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:-

http://jsfiddle.net/ubvgt/

```
   $(':Submit').click(function(){
    var elem = $('[name=testxtoadd]');
    elem.before( $('<input>' , {type: "checkbox",value: elem.val() })).
    before(elem.val() + "</br>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am seeing an an Error when I try to run the same program locally as:uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Submit. it works in the link you provided am I missng anything

Comment: I tried that it is not working . infact I created a small div and tried :$("div.main submit.Submit").click(function()..even than it is not working am I missing something ..it works the way I want in the example you privided me

Comment: Are you adding it in document.ready? i.e $(function(){//your code here});

Comment: yes. actually what you mentioned worked..but $("div.main submit.Submit").click(function(){
is nt working is there any issue in the above one?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29073/discussion-between-the-learner-and-pscoder)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/awihuf/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(':submit').click(function(){

  var val = $('[name=testxtoadd]').val();

  if( $.trim(val) ){         // THIS WILL PREVENT EMPTY SUBMIT
      var newHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="'+val+'"> '+ val +'<br>';
      $(this).prev().before( newHTML );
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the input fields id, so that you can know from which input field each text came from.

You can use a listener that listens to your actions so that once you press the submit button, a listener notices it and it can check for the values of all the input fields, and you can easily get the values and handle them like you want.

You can add the text somewhere on the page, by having a div with an id, and then you tell the element with "that id" to receive the values;

```
$('#divId').html(inputTextThatWasSelected);
```

I can be more precise if you make your question be more precise :)